# SpringXD module delete command does not delete the uploaded .jar file

Tags: spring-data, spring-batch, spring-xd

**Issue**

SpringXD's module delete command is deleting the module from SpringXD DIRT (module list command does not show the delete module) but is not deleting the uploaded .jar file in /xd/custom-modules/job directory. The reason is that .jar file is used by a java process even after the deployed module is deleted from SpringXD DIRT. If I restart the admin and container I can delete the file.

using module upload command with --force option results in following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not install Uploaded module
>   'job:ang-im-job' at location file
>   [C:\install_dir\xd\custom-modules\job\batch-job.jar]
>   as that file already exists

I am using SpringXD 1.2 and on Windows 7. Is this something to do with OS?

Below are the scripts, I am going to parameterize them and integrate with automated deployment tool so that same scirpts can be used for deploying modules in SpringXD DIRT.

**upload_module.bat**

> set
>   ASSEMBLY_PATH=C:\path_to_assembly\batch-job-01.00.00.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
>
> set MODULE_NAME=batch-job
>
> set MODULE_TYPE=job
>
> cd %XD_INSTALL_DIR%\shell\bin\
>
> xd-shell module upload --force --file %ASSEMBLY_PATH% --name
>   %MODULE_NAME% --type %MODULE_TYPE%

**deploy_job.bat**

> set MODULE_NAME=batch-job
>
> set DEPLOY_JOB_NAME=batch-job
>
> cd %XD_INSTALL_DIR%\shell\bin\
>
> xd-shell job create --name %DEPLOY_JOB_NAME% --definition
>   "%MODULE_NAME%" --deploy

**destroy_job.bat**

> set DEPLOY_JOB_NAME=batch-job
>
> cd %XD_INSTALL_DIR%\shell\bin\
>
> xd-shell job destroy --name %DEPLOY_JOB_NAME%

**delete_module.bat**

> set MODULE_NAME=batch-job
>
> cd %XD_INSTALL_DIR%\shell\bin\
>
> xd-shell module delete --name job:%MODULE_NAME%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with the OS. On Windows module delete command is not deleting the .jar file after it deletes from SpringXD DIRT environment. No such issues on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, though the XD shell said the below error, i don't see the module in admin-ui

```
xd:>module delete --name job:reverseJob

Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Could
not delete module 'job:reverseJob'
```